# Javascript - Is it possible to change location, and start manipulating the new document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to switch between pages and then to manipulate the new document through javascript or jQuery.

However, when I run my example, it manipulates the first document and then changes location. Is it even possible?

this is my example(i even tried to call a function after changing location):

```
function openSide(x) {
            //é passado o botão carregado   
        window.location.href = 'new.php';
        var id = x.innerHTML;
        open(id);

    }

function open(x) {

        $("#div1").css("display","none");
        $("#div2").css("display","");
        $("#tituloPlay").html(id);


          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
                $("#tabelaOuvirPlaylist").append(xhttp.responseText);
                //console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("POST", "php/listarMusicasDePlaylist.php", true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhttp.send("id="+ x);



        }
```

Comment: No..once new page loaded old script is gone. Can't manipulate a new page from existing page. Use url params to pass id to new page

Comment: So you're trying to go to an another location on the same page page, but trying to manipulate the new page right? In a such case, you can pretty easily understand why old scripts are unloaded for some obvious security reasons...

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This is a playlist sharing application, i was trying to be more pratical by using scripts i already had in another page, instead of creating new divs on my html and creating new scripts

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery load() method to take data from that location and put it on your page. Then you can manipulate it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're opening a new PHP page, why don't you just pass the ID as a query parameter?

new.php?id=1

Adjust your PHP file to read the ID from $_GET ["id"]..
To use the ID in Javascript you would need to read the current location and do a substring the = sign or you could have PHP create a hidden DOM element and read it's value in Javascript